# falsey var showing undefined in console.log

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, knockout.js, durandal

> 

```js
var statusDatesDescending = ko.computed(function () {
  var result = cachedSortExpression() === "StringValue";
  logger.log(result);
  return result;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

The following provides this in the console when result is false:

**logger.log("DESCENDING: ", result);
DESCENDING: undefined**

The following provides this in the console when result is true:

**logger.log("DESCENDING: ", result);
DESCENDING: true**

Comment: What happens when you do `logger.log(false)`?

Comment: 'var result = false'
'undefined'
'result'
'false'
'console.log(result)'
'undefined'

Comment: console.log(falseyVar)  is undefined.

Comment: Wait, are you using `logger.log` or is that a typo? If you're using a logging utility, there may be a bug/feature that converts values. If you're using `console.log`, then there's nothing wrong with it; what you're probably seeing is the *return value* of `console.log`, which is nothing.

Comment: My response was confusing. I tried it with both Durandal's logger.log and the native console.log Thanks for responding.

Answer (score 2):

What you might seeing is the return from `console.log`, as seen here, if you are using an interactive console.

[image]

Notice how `false` is logged before `undefined`. The `console.log` call executes, logging to the console, and then returns undefined. The return value of the call is shown because the interactive console always shows the result of any functions you enter into it.

Comment: thank you for responding. For the case in question, 'false' was not appearing. Just the undefined.

Comment: I see your updated code snippet makes this answer obsolete. Unfortunately I cannot delete an answer with upvotes